# LinkButton postback problem inside custom WebControl

Tags: asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I've given up trying to find a solution to this.
My page has a ModalPopupExtender that shows an asp:Panel with my custom WebControl inside it.
My custom WebControl contains only a LinkButton and is inside an UpdatePanel.

**The problem is that, when clicked, the LinkButton it is reloading the entire page.**
With a regular input Button, this does not happen. The LinkButton refuses to work as expected and reloads the entire page :(

If I use the LinkButton alone inside the UpdatePanel (not inside my custom WebControl) everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?!?
Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1379865/2920158.aspx).

[Please register LinkButton as AsyncPostBack control](http://weblogs.asp.net/wallym/archive/2006/09/26/Programmatically-adding-triggers-to-an-UpdatePanel-_2D00_-Microsoft-AJAX-Library-and-ASP.NET-2.0-AJAX-Extensions.aspx).