# LinkButton in custom Control not rendering ID (or really working at all)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I am guessing this could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511445/linkbutton-postback-problem-inside-custom-webcontrol) but unfortunately the workaround doesn't seem to work in this case.

After struggling with the larger implementation not working, I boiled it down to the simplest case. This does not work.

```
   public class MyButton : Control
    {
        public MyButton()
            : base()
        {
            LinkButton but = new LinkButton();
            but.CommandName = "test";
            but.CommandArgument = "test2";
            but.Text = "Click Here";
            Controls.Add(but);
        }
    }
```

What renders is:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl11$ctl07','')">Click Here</a>
```

There are two major problems here. First, there is no ID. It should have tag `id='ctl00$ctl11$ctl07'`. So even though it will post, the events never get captured.

Second, it's ignoring the CommandName and CommandArgument, it should be rendering `__doPostBackWithOptions` anyway.

Am I being immensely stupid and just overlooking something obvious or is this a huge bug in ASP.NET?

I've done this lots of times before where there were many other controls rendered inside a `Control` or `WebControl` and never had any problems, so it must have something to do with the simplicity rather than the complexity, I guess.

If anyone can help me solve this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you should implement [INamingContainer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)

Comment: Makes no difference. Nor should it. INamingContainer only has to do with ensuring uniqueness in user-assigned IDs in a container. This isn't a repeater and doesn't assign any of its own IDs.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: it does make a difference, the ID is in the context of the ID I used for the control, instead of the context of the page. But it still doesn't work, it doesn't render it's own ID and it doesn't render the correct postback javascript. I did try that (among about a million other things) already  :)

Comment: My fault. I actually think you should inherit LinkButton `public class MyButton : LinkButton` or inherit this control from `CompositeControl` and override `CreateChildControls` method where you will set LinkButton.ID

Answer (score 0):

Set the ID property of your button.

```
but.ID = "MyLinkButtonID";
 but.Command += new CommandEventHandler(EVENTHANDLER);
```

If the button is always a member of the class add the button as a member and add it to the Controls collection in the OnInit event.

Forgot to add the event handler for the Command Event.

Comment: Yeah-- I just forgot to put the command event handler in this simple case. Though it's not necessary to assign an ID.  I think I have been fixating on the javascript it's rendering for postback, which I realized isn't always "withoptions" for a linkbutton. I'm starting to think that my problem is that I was (originally) using a WebControl but overriding Render and not emitting the wrapper. Which, in absence of a naming container, would make it not work since it in the context of the outer ID. Anyway -- this example does actually work, so apparently I am being immensely stupid somehow.

Answer (score 0):

ARGH! I am kicking myself, the answer is actually a naming container problem. This was one of those situations where all I could do was focus on some detail, which wasn't actually the problem.

My custom control gets emitted by another control... into yet a third control. But there can be several instances of "third control." (The big picture is, I'm making something that will allow me to put a copy of form control buttons both before and after a form. The main control determines which buttons to emit for a given form.).

So the "third control" was not a naming container. And that was killing it. But I never got any errors about ID conflicts, it just didn't work.